# Showing deciseconds in the homescreen

Tags: clock

I am interested in a clock app that in addition to seconds also shows deciseconds.

I searched and could not find one yet. Is there any widget for Android that shows deciseconds (like this: 11:51:32.1)?

Comment: I'm unsure if that level of accuracy is even available in Android.

Comment: A timer or stopwatch type of apps may provide this feature, but I doubt any "regular" clock apps would.  Why do you need such level of clock accuracy?  Is there a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not sure why there are votes to close here. This is a valid question for this site.

Comment: Agreed with @AlEverett.  I thought that maybe close votes were for "app shopping" reason, but they are all for "too localized".

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you reverted the previous edits to your question? You have re-introduced several grammar and spelling errors for no immediately obvious reason.

Comment: @Chahk Viewing deciseconds beside seconds shows how fast time is passing and may motivate me to wordk faster!!!

Comment: Well, now you've made the question about finding an app again, rather than about a problem to be solved. "I need an app that does X" questions don't do well here. Please read our [FAQ].

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to create a widget that updates that often, because it will suck your battery really quickly. There are many stopwatch apps available in the Play Store. Many of them have millisecond or decisecond accuracy, but I'm not aware of any that have an associated widget.

These kind of high precision timers should only be needed on a case-to-case basis, so it's not worth it for them to be on the homescreen.